# Inconsistent ajax loading/rendering

Tags: javascript, jstree

I've been using jstree for a few weeks now and I have a strange inconsistent behavior that all my users report.

Most of the time the tree renders well with ajax. Like this: 
[image]

But sometimes it renders without any + or links between nodes like this:
[image]

A simple refresh (F5) often solves the problem for me but some users report not being able to render the normal tree even after a refresh.

Also the loading sign (since I'm using ajax) is different when it won't render properly but rather in as if in a  tag.

Normal loading:

[image]

Loading when it won't work properly (green is the style of ):

[image]

Did anybody ever have this bug? Can anyone help me with that?

For references, here's the [identical post on jstree forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/MGatIISpCjw)